# Restoring 'bloatware' on a Samsung Galaxy S7

Tags: restore, bloatware, samsung-galaxy-s7

I have rooted and customised my phone and I am loving it. I just realised that I have removed without backing up a few of the Samsung bloatware apps (notably the Samsung Keyboard). Is there a simple way to restore these original apps? It's not a great concern unless down the line I need to reset the phone. I am pretty sure the setup wizard will want the Samsung Keyboard.

EDIT - before posting this I should have looked myself. I have found the Samsung Keyboard APK file and apparently can load that.

Answer (score 0):

Are you still looking for other bloatware? If I'm not wrong, they should be easily downloaded on Samsung app store.

Comment: Thanks, I will look that up. I managed to load the keyboard, but while I am doing this I will save the other packages for restoration.